# Writing equation in LaTeX: some part are mysterious to me :)

Tags: math-mode, equations

I would like to write in LaTeX two equations:

[image: equation1]

and

[image]

I do not know how to do that...Particularly, how to write stuff underneath the max function. And also how to have this line over `Wi` or `Wj`.

PS: I do not ask for the whole equations, I am asking for the part that I do not know how to write in LaTeX :))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the case of `\max`, the text below automatically. For other operators (like `\int`) or for inline formulas, you can use `\limits`. Longer text has to be in curly brackets:

```
\max\limits_{n_j \in succ(n_i)}
```

To get a line over your text, you can use `\overline`:

```
\overline{w_i}
```

Your formulas would be:

```
rank_u(n_i) = \overline{w_i} + \max\limits_{n_j \in succ(n_i)} (\overline{c_{ij}} + rank_u(n_j))
rank_d(n_i) = \max\limits_{n_j \in pred(n_i)} \{rank_d(n_j) + \overline{w_j} + \overline{c_{i,j}}\}
```

If you want to typeset *rank* and *succ* as an operator like max, you can either use `\text{rank}` from `amsmath`, or declare *rank* as a math operator (in your preamble):

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
\DeclareMathOperator{\successor}{succ}
```

Please note that I chose `\successor` over `\succ`, as this is already used for a math symbol.

Comment: If the material material is typeset in displaymath mode, it is *not* necessary to use the `\limits` directive to inform LaTeX that the argument of the `\max` command should be typeset below the string "max".

Comment: You're right, in the case of `\max` in displaymath it is not necessary. I've thought of other operators like `\int`where one would need `\limits`. I've corrected this.

Comment: Thanks for this solution: I chose this one for my document :)

Comment: @Mrjay42 You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 16):

To have LaTeX place some material *below* below the string "max", simply use the macro `\max_{...}`: If you're in displaymath mode (which you will be if you're in an environment such as `equation`), this will result in the argument of the `\max` command being placed below (rather than in a subscript position) the string "max".

Separately, I would recommend that you typeset the strings "rank", "pred", and "succ" in upright-roman characters since they denote math "operators". One way to do this is to load the `amsmath` package and use its `\DeclareMathOperator` instruction to define the corresponding macros `\rank`, `\pred`, and `\succ`. Aside: Because the macro `\succ` already exists -- and creates a math symbol that looks like a curvy `>` sign -- it has to be undefined first before it can be redefined as a math operator. Obviously, if you need to use the original meaning of `\succ` elsewhere in your document, you should *not* redefine it to act as a math operator; instead, devise a new macro name, e.g., `\succeeds`.

Furthermore, I would use the `\bar` instruction to create lines above the "c" and "w" characters. Doing so creates horizontal lines that aren't quite as "heavy" as those produced by `\overline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \DeclareOperator macro and align environment
\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
\DeclareMathOperator{\pred}{pred}
\let\succ\relax % undefine \succ first
\DeclareMathOperator{\succ}{succ} % now redefine it as an "operator"
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\rank_u(n_i)&=\bar{w}_i + \max_{n_j\in\succ(n_i)}
  \bigl(\bar{c}_{i,j}+\rank_u(n_j)\bigr)\\
\rank_d(n_i)&=\bar{w}_i + \max_{n_j\in\pred(n_i)}
  \bigl\{ \rank_d(n_j)+\bar{w}_j+\bar{c}_{j,i}\bigr\}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Might be an idea to note that users should be very careful about redefining macros and only do so when they are exactly sure they know what the original macros does and that it is OK to change it. `\span` is the obvious example of what not to change.

Comment: @daleif - Excellent point! :-) I'll add an explicit note about this to my answer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to save the old definition just in case?

Answer (score -1):

```
$rank_u{(n_i)}=\overline{w_i} +\max_{n_j\in\succ(n_i)}(\overline{c_i,_j}+rank_u{(n_j))}$


$rank_u{(n_i)}=\overline{w_i} +\max_{n_j\in\succ(n_i)}(\overline{c_i,_j}+rank_u{(n_j))}$
```

Comment: And the magic is what? Don't just dump some code.